# CSS styles are not doing what they should

Tags: html, css

My first venture into writing HTML is not going so well. I'm usually quite adept at finding out how to do things but in this case, the solutions given are just not working.

Here's my latest head scratcher:

```
<div style="margin-top: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px; float: right; width: 55.45%;">
    <div id="home" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: left;">
        <a href="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="options" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: right;">
        <a href="_blank"></a>
    </div>  
    <div id="settings" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <a href="_blank"></a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Forgive the inline styles, they allow me to edit on the fly.

The above should center the third `<div>` between the two floaters, but I just cannot get it to work. The outer container is stretched correctly, the "home" and "options" divisions are also placed correctly. But, "settings" is butted up to "home".

This is just one example of things not working. Others include centering vertically (almost all methods) and rearranging vertical order according to media queries. I tested code on chrome and IE10, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in my code, but I can't find it.

1. What is the best debugging tool?
   I currently use chrome's built in element viewer as it shows me which styles are applied. But, it's just not powerful enough.
2. Is there a visual IDE which displays the result as you type? Switching between 'Netbeans' and 'chrome' is a time waster. I should note here that any IDE needs to work with my server since I'm also coding PHP.
3. What could be causing the problems I'm seeing? Is it a missing style or something to do with how elements are sized?
4. What styles should I be checking for further up the chain that may cause hard to find bugs later?

Thanks in advance

Update: Answer found.
I'm posting here in-case anybody with a similar problem finds it useful.
The containing `<div>` is itself being positioned with `float: right;`. For some reason contained items are affected by this. If somebody would like to write up an answer explaining why I gladly accept it. Adding `float: none;` to the center item fixed the problem.

Comment: you've got an extra " in the anchor on line 3

Comment: If people want to downvote, at least state why. I see nothing wrong with my question but if it isn't suitable I'll happily change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width of div to 33.33% and simplify it like this:

HTML

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="home" class="button-style">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="options" class="button-style">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">options</a>
    </div>
    <div id="settings" class="button-style">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">settings</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#container {
    margin: 9px 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 55.45%;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
#container>div {
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    *width:33%; /* fix for IE7 rounding bug */
    text-align:center;
}
#container>div:hover {
    background-color: #fdd;
}
#container a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; zoom:1; /*IE7 fix for inline-block */
    width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMtQS/2/show): http://jsfiddle.net/CMtQS/2/

Comment: It's a good idea but my divs are actually buttons. They can't be resized. I could give each an extra layer and center within that but, in my opinion, it's not fixing the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using position CSS attributes for the third div. You told it should have auto margins, but not where it should be placed.

For example :

```
<div id="settings" class="button-style" style="width: 4px;position:absolute; left:10px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

Try specifying attributes according to your convenience

Comment: Doesn't work even with hardcoded positions for left and right. Also, I can't hardcode, they need to be dynamic for a fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order  elements using CSS float, you should just order them correctly and float them all to the same side.

```
<div id="home" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: left;">
    <a href="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div id="settings" class="button-style" style="width: 4px;float: left; text-align:center">
    <a href="_blank"></a>
</div> 
<div id="options" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: left;">
    <a href="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

The third  is now centered between the other two.

Comment: You're missing the point. It should be centered not just positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-order your HTML, here is an example

DEMO http:http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/UKL4B/2/

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px; float: right; width: 55.45%;">
    <div id="home" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: left;">
        <a href="_blank">1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="options " class="button-style " style="width: 4px; float: right; ">
        <a href="_blank ">3</a>
    </div>  
    <div id="settings " class="button-style " style="width: 4px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; ">
        <a href="_blank ">2</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

In this example: The first div floats left, the second div float right and then the third div fills the gap(providing it has space). That is how HTML works.

A good tool for debugging CSS and HTML is google dev tools in `google chrome`. For debugging javascript i'd recommend firebug on `firefox`

Comment: I've been using dev tools, as mentioned in the post, but it's not powerful enough. That, or I'm just using it wrong.

Comment: re order what? the code you posted is the same. float left then right then center. That is what I have done.

Comment: You can't get it to work, it says in your question. It works fine in my example. There are issues within your code that are not present in this question. Please update your question with more code from your page.

Comment: I noted in my OP that it should work but doesn't and that the error must be somewhere else. The problem is, I don't know where or how to find the error. It's just too much code to post here.

Comment: have you got a link to the site so one of us could take a look?

Comment: It's currently hosted on my own PC. I'm nowhere near ready to upload it my file host. Thanks for the offer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center;
```

on the centered div seems to solve the problem.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMtQS/)

Comment: not working. Also, align center would be for that div's content, not the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.
1. About your code not aligning

are you trying to achieve this[image]

If yes then try the following code

```
<div style="margin-top: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px; float: right; width: 55.45%;height: 10px;">
            <div id="home" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: left;height:10px; background: blue;">
                <a href="_blank""></a>
                </div>
                <div id="options" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; float: right; height: 10px; background: green;">
                <a href="_blank"></a>
            </div>  
            <div id="settings" class="button-style" style="width: 4px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background: green; height:10px;">
                <a href="_blank"></a>
            </div>
```

Make sure to add content and remove height from styles as the height may remain auto.

2. Not sure why you have 1 div floating left, 1 floating right and 1 not floating at all.
3. If your divs are floating then you may have to fix their width (Good you already did) and have their heights set to auto for it to automatically adjust.

4 finally your questions:
     i. What is the best debugging tool? I currently use chrome's built in element viewer as it shows me which styles are applied. But, it's just not powerful enough **[Try using Firefox alongwith Firebug which allows you debug you code on the fly]**
      ii. Is there a visual IDE which displays the result as you type? Switching between 'Netbeans' and 'chrome' is a time waster. I should note here that any IDE needs to work with my server since I'm also coding PHP **[Firebug itself can help you do the same within javascript(Not sure about php)]**
      iii. What could be causing the problems I'm seeing? Is it a missing style or something to do with how elements are sized **[All you need to do here is to have a fixed height if elements are empty or have height set to auto if they contain something, Please see that you need to add line-height to the elements in order to have them vertically aligned as I assume that the elements contain text]**

**And most importantly try avoiding position:absolute as this causes misalignments in different browsers at times**

Comment: It isn't a height issue. All height are applied in the (not shown) button styles. They show up clearly just not in the right place. I'll look into Firebug, thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

It's working and all, but you haven't really *fixed* it. (=

If your plan is to pull the css out and include a .css file, then you should consider using flexbox

[Flexbox primer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

It really eliminates goofy float rules and quirky positioning. If you intend on using css for any lenght of time, I urge you to sink your teeth into it.